# How to sign xml with X509Certificate in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, certificate, signer

I'm trying to sign a xml with a X509Certificate, i'm using the signer gem.

```
private_key_file = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/cert/1234567890001_priKEY.pem')

cert_file        = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '/cert/1234567890001_certKEY.pem')

input_xml_file   = File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'nfce_xml.xml')
signer = Signer.new(File.read(input_xml_file))
signer.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(cert_file))
signer.private_key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(File.read(private_key_file), "")
signer.security_node = signer.document.root
signer.security_token_id = ""
signer.digest!(signer.document.root, :id => "NFe51150501882109000162650010000000011064552496", :enveloped => true)
signer.sign!(:issuer_serial => true)
signed_xml = signer.to_xml

File.open("signed.xml", 'w') {|f| f.write(signed_xml) }
```

the signature:

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <Reference URI="#NFe51150501882109000162650010000000011064552496">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <DigestValue>xgvKmWBZeQSt0vue30DzzBvc494=</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>DE8BKKsxBAh/zEnX/N/P0f/xOZD7O...</SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509IssuerSerial>
        <X509IssuerName>System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X500DistinguishedName</X509IssuerName>
        <X509SerialNumber>2701224559233645315</X509SerialNumber>
      </X509IssuerSerial>
      <X509Certificate>MIIIHzCCBgegAwIBAgIIJXytbMe...</X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
</Signature>
```

but i need remove the X509IssuerSerial tag, add this transform:

```
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
```

and also change CanonicalizationMethod to:

```
<CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
```

Someone can help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do about format.

Captain obvious suggests to disable issuer_serial in `signer.sign!(:issuer_serial => true)` to remove the X509IssuerSerial tag?